# How to get a list of google cloud quota requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We're splitting up our GCP project.   Is there any way to get a list of quota requests we've made for the original project so that we can make similar requests for the new projects?   Because of course you can't just request an increase to CPU count, you also need to increase IP addresses, SSD and probably several others I've forgotten...

Comment: You should be able to cross-reference the https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas page between the two accounts. There's also an API you could use, if you wanted to script it.

Comment: that list is 29 pages long, there should be something easier.  :)

Comment: That's where the API comes in.